# Jquery Click Event in if Else Statement With Same Class but Different IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, if-statement

In my code I have two buttons with the same class and different ids. As the two buttons need to do similar things (specifically information from an ajax request) I first called the two buttons by their class and am trying set up an if else statement that will add the final pieces of the functionality for the buttons based on their IDs. However, right now the second button's else statement doesn't appear to be running and instead when I press the second button I see the changes that are supposed to happen to the first button occur. Any suggestions on how to get the li to appear correctly for the else statement?

```
$(".consumeFood").on("click",function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:url,
},
error:function(err){
},
complete:function(s){
  $.ajax({
    },
    success: function(r){
    if ($(".consumeFood".id=="eat")){
$('#eaten').append("<li class='left'>"+inputInfo+"</li>");
    }
    else if($("#consumeFood".id=="possibleEat")){
      $('#want').append("<li class='right'>"+input+"</li>");

    }
```

Html

```
    <form id='first'class="" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="what have you eaten" name="item" id="inputID" value="" class="toEat">
        <button id="eat" class=consumeFood>Add food</button>
    </form>
    <ol id="eaten">
    </ol>

    <form id="second" class="" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="any foods you would like to eat" name="item2"id="wantToEat" class="toEat">

        <button id="possibeEat"class="consumeFood">include</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: what are these 2  statements doing `if ($(".consumeFood".id=="eat")){` , `else if($("#consumeFood".id=="possibleEat")){` do you think they are correct ? .

Comment: These lines are identifying starts the information for the individual buttons. "eat" being one button and "possibleEat" being the other.

Comment: should'nt they be in the following way `if($(".consumed").attr('id')=='eat'){` , `else if ($(".consumeFood").attr('id')=='possibleEat')` , secondly you are doing it the wrong way both of them have the same class and the function would be binded to both the buttons every time. You need to decide when you want to bind both of these buttons depending on the response received from the ajax call. i mean `if(response.someid=='eat'){// then bind the eat button` , `else if(response.someId=='possibleEat'){//bind the possibleEat button`

Comment: By reformatting to do if($(".consumed").attr('id')=='eat') it allows for a new li to be created for the second button but it is added to both ols. The ajax request is dependent on the inputs. For example, If I write "oreo" the ajax on submit will give me information about "oreos".

Comment: see below i posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still trying to actually understand what you are doing and maybe I still not have understood but think this should solve your problem

```
 $(".consumeFood").on("click",function(){
var buttonId=$(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
        url:url,
    },
    error:function(err){
    },
    complete:function(s){
      $.ajax({
        },
        success: function(r){
        if (buttonId=="eat"){
    $('#eaten').append("<li class='left'>"+inputInfo+"</li>");
        }
        else if(buttonId=="possibeEat"){
          $('#want').append("<li class='right'>"+input+"</li>");

        }
```

do consider the variables `inputInfo` and `input` i hope they are coming from somewhere above in the script and they have a valid value.

Comment: I just tried this with my code and this doesn't seem to get the else if statement to run still. And yes, the inputInfo and Input are variables which are defined as the values enter into the fields correlating with the appropriate button.

Comment: there is a typo in the id of the input possibleEat it is possibeEat , check if that aint the reason, in you HTML input button id i am talking about,

Comment: Ah yes. That solved it. Thank you so much. You have been a great help.

Comment: no problem glad it helped you, do select the right answer so that others having the same problem also get the benefit.